# Need to trigger Jenkins when commit is done in Tortoise SVN

Tags: svn, jenkins

I have placed my code in Tortoise SVN. I have integrated the SVN to Jenkins. I need to build the code for every checkin.

I am using MS Build. I have integrated SVN with Visual Studio.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get jenkins to build every revision of a subversion repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8310979/how-do-i-get-jenkins-to-build-every-revision-of-a-subversion-repository)

Answer (score 2):

In source code management, select scm as svn and add the svn location. And in build trigger's select poll scm and say if you want to run the polling if someone has checked in last 15 minutes use pattern like

```
*/15 * * * *
```

For further details you could even check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014252/jenkins-ci-how-to-trigger-builds-on-svn-commit)